# Connecting to a SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql

What is the syntax for connecting to a specific instance of a sql server database?

Here's my code:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
conn1 = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "ARC-WEB/SKWSPATIAL"], 
  "UserName" -> "Mathematica", databasename = "XYZ_Database", 
  "Password" -> "xxxxx"]
```

I have no problem connecting to ARC-WEB but cannot connect to one of the other instances.
Mathematica 9.0
SQL Server 2008

Comment: Did you try `"Name"->"XYZ_Database"`? To me `databasename = "XYZ_Database"` does not look like a correct syntax..

Comment: I changed to code from databasename to Name and no changes.

Comment: You used a `=` instead of `->` for an option. You seem to have forgotten the quotes as well.

Comment: You have database name that, I think, should be "Name", i.e. in quotes.  You also have = not -> for that option.

Comment: @Sjoerd - Snap :)

Comment: @Ymareth Great minds think alike

Comment: Are you getting an error message, java exception or $Failed?  What is the output of the OpenSQLConnection call?

Answer (score 2):

After looking at all the comments I was able to come up the following code that allows me to connect and query the database:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
conn1 = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "ARC-WEB"], 
  "UserName" -> "Mathematica", "Instance" -> "SKWSPATIAL", 
  "database" -> "yyy", "Password" -> "xxx"]
```

Thanks for all your help!